# How to fetch API Key using aws CLI

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli, api-key, api-gateway

I have a script where I want to fetch the AWS API gateway ID and API key value. So far I have been able to get the API gateway ID using the cli:

```
aws apigateway get-api-keys --query 'items[?name==`my-api-key-name`].id' --output text --region us-east-1
```

But I am unable to fetch the value of API key. I have tried the following cli, but no luck:

```
aws apigateway get-api-keys --query 'items[?name==`my-api-key-name`].value' --output text --region us-east-1
```

Can someone assist me on this please?

Answer (score 8):

You're missing `--include-values` key.

You can try this:

```
aws apigateway get-api-keys --query 'items[?name==`my-api-key-name`].value' --include-values --output text --region us-east-1
```

or this:

```
aws apigateway get-api-key --api-key <api-key-id> --include-value --query "value" --output text
```

[Here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/apigateway/get-api-keys.html) you can find more info on that.

UPD:
Included suggestion from @Anatolii Bivol to use `--query "value"`

Comment: Thanks for looking into it @dmigo. The 'get-api-keys' does not throw an error, but it does not provide the API Key's value. The 'get-api-key' throws an error when trying to fetch the API Key value using the <api-key-id> as it is expecting the API Key value itself. I have been able to fetch the API Key id using the 'get-api-keys' ; and then using terraform I am fetching the API Key's value by passing this api ID.

Comment: @Satya does `aws apigateway get-api-keys --query 'items[?name==\`my-api-key-name\`]' --include-values --output text --region us-east-1` return anything?

Comment: My variation of this as a bash function https://gist.github.com/vladgolubev/08551d4b6555d52304f6b4e9bfcd7634

Comment: `aws apigateway get-api-key --api-key {keyId} --include-value --query "value" --output text`

Comment: My command above will get the value of the api key. Sorry can not edit comment after 5min.